Angular material mat-slider does not react to programmatically triggered event
I want to create test for mat-slider but looks that it doesn't react to events dispatched programmatically
@Component({
    selector: 'slider-show',
    templateUrl: 'slider-show.html',
})
export class SliderShow {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    dispatchFakeEvent() {
        const matSlider = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-slider-ticks');
        const dimensions = matSlider.getBoundingClientRect();
        const percentage = 0.5;

        matSlider.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window,
            detail: 0,
            clientX: Math.round(dimensions.right * percentage),
            clientY: Math.round(dimensions.bottom * percentage)
        }));
    }
}

<mat-slider>
    <input matSliderThumb>
</mat-slider>

<button (click)="dispatchFakeEvent()">
    ACTION
</button>

In material version 6 that works, any ideas why it doesn't work now or how to resolve it?

Which Angular Material version you are using now?

@YongShun - angular material 15.2.9

Because from Angular 15, the Material components are migrated to MDC-based components. This will have big changes/and impacts especially when you are trying to manipulate the event by class name. I think this could be complex if you want to achieve/migrate your current way. You can set the MatSlideThumb value as this demo, but unfortunately this will lose the animation as what you have in Angular 6.

Maybe you can refer to slider.spec.ts
